# Random unicode characters while typing normally in Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode

Sometimes when I'm typing in Windows I get some unicode-variant of the character I was trying to type.

for example:

- ŕ instead of r
- ś instead of s
- ḳ instead of k etc.

### Things I've already tried:

- Try another keyboard (from a differtent Brand / model)
- Try another USB-port
- Formatted laptop and reinstalled Windows 10

### Things to consider:

I'm using a **non-standard keyboard layout**. Before formatting my laptop I tried using the standard US International layout but it didn't help.
I'm using a Windows version of the **English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)** keyboard layout. To be specific: [this one](https://www.scottseverance.us/html/keyboard/win_intl_altgr/)

Before I formatted my laptop I used a different 3rd-party layout from github which I suspected to be the problem: [US Reformed International](https://github.com/barkloaf/US-Reformed-International)

I have no idea how to debug this any further. The fact that the occurences are quite rare makes it hard to test. Depending on how much I type it will occur once or twice a day or not even at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99.99% sure I have found the problem. It seems to be that sometimes for some reason Microsoft's **PowerToys Quick Accent** seems to be triggered (because of some system hiccup I guess). It's so fast I never saw it until this one time.

This theory seems to fit because if I manually trigger Quick Accent and release immediately it creates exactly the same accented letters as I got "randomly" before.

Also the accented letters always showed up at the end of a word and pressing `space` while holding down a letter invokes Quick Accent so this makes a lot of sense.